# df and system report incorrect disk capacity of raid5 array

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I have a new Adaptec 8405 sata raid controller and started with 3x WD Red 4TB drives giving me a 8TB array (or actually 7.3TB). 
I installed Ubuntu on a seperate 500GB WD Green and mounted the array at /data
I then recently bought a 4th WD Red 4TB drive and expanded the array (through the controller bios) 
Now my system reports that the array is still only 7.3TB and is 90% used.

```
/dev/sda        7.3T  6.3T  603G  92% /data
```

Webmin Reports

```
Disk name       Total size      Make and model      Partitions   
SCSI device A   11.17 TB        ASR8405 Data        1
```

How can I make "df -h" report the right capacity and usage?

Comment: I ran sync and that changed nothing.

Comment: Could you please run 'gparted' and show us the output ? You might have to expand the filesystem to use the added space.

Answer (score 3):

You need to expand the partition. That's what's limiting this now.

I'm not sure what filesystem you're using, but the safest method (usually if you can't unmount it) is to drop into a LiveCD and use Gparted to edit the partition to fill the array.

Comment: more than likely, you'll need `resize2fs` unless you deliberately picked a filesystem other than the default.  xfs uses `xfs_grow` and reiserfs uses `resize_reiserfs` and others have other methods for expanding the filesystem.

Comment: The array has been fully expanded and has data written to it.
The partition has expanded it to the full capacity.
The OS still thinks it is  
/dev/sda        7.3T  7.0T     0 100% /data
I want the OS to realise its full capacity but it doesn't!
Webmin reports the truth 
SCSI device A  11.17 TB  ASR8405 Data

Comment: I think I used gparted to grow the partition after the raid card expanded the array.

Answer (score 2):

I was forced to boot to a live USB to correct something else and thought I would try `resize2fs` first.

I ran:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda
```

Then:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/sda' first.
```

So I then ran:

```
$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity /lost+found not found.     
Create<y>? yes
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
data: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
data: 177679/244121600 files (10.1% non-contiguous), 1776221118/1952970240 blocks
```

And finally ran:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/sda to 2929456640 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/sda is now 2929456640 (4k) blocks long.
```

And now `df -h` reports:

```
/dev/sda         11T  6.6T  3.8T  64% /media/ubuntu/data
```